# How to get configuration params in Controller Console in Yii2 Framework

Tags: yii2

How to get configuration `params` in Console Controller in Yii2 Framework

I try below code but its not working

```
Yii::$app->params['params_1']
```

Comment: Where have you specified your params array?

Comment: in /config/params.php

Comment: are you using advanced or basic template?

Comment: i'm using basic template

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try This:

Code in config/params.php

```
    <?php
    return   array(
                    'apptitle' => 'stackOverlfow', 
                   //Define PARAMS as you need.
                );
    ?>
```

You can use PARAM as below:

```
\Yii::$app->params['apptitle'];
```

Example:

```
echo "App title is:". \Yii::$app->params['apptitle'];
```

Comment: thank a lot, i forget to add backslash when call Yii::$app->params['param_1'];

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned **Basic Template** Of **Yii**.

**config/web.php**

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
  'id' => 'basic',
  'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
  'bootstrap' => ['log'],
  'components' => [
    .
    .
    .
  ],
  'params' => $params,
];

return $config;
?>
```

**config/params.php**

```
<?php
$params = [
  'params_1' => 'YourValue'
];

return $params;
?>
```

**SomeWhere.php**

```
<?=Yii::$app->params['params_1'];?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you insert your param to other conf params.php.
 My helper function:

```
/**
 * Get param value from config file.
 * Получение параметра из конфигурационного файла
 *
 * @param string $param_name название пареметра
 *
 * @return string|ApicoServerErrorHttpException Значение параметра
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public static function yiiparam($param_name)
{
    if (isset(\Yii::$app->params[$param_name])) {
        return \Yii::$app->params[$param_name];
    } else {
        $msg = "Can not find param in configuration file. have been search by param = " . VarDumper::export($param_name);
        \Yii::error($msg, __METHOD__);
        throw new ServerErrorHttpException();
    }
}
```